# How many truth tables if there are only $\land$ or $\lor$ for $n$ variables?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

For example, if we have three operators $\land, \lor$ and $\neg$. For $n$ variables, there will be $2^{2^n}$ different truth tables. Because for $2^n$ rows of the truth table, there are $2$ choices - $T/F$.

However, if we have only two operators $\land$ and $\lor$, how many truth tables will be left for $n$ variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really asking how many different boolean functions of $n$ variables can be constructed using $\land$ and $\lor$.  Assuming you don't allow empty expressions (always true or always false), this is OEIS sequence [A007153](http://oeis.org/A007153).

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be the variables and $\phi(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ an expression in these using only $\land$ and $\lor$ as connectives. Then we can rewrite this as $$\phi(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\iff v_n\land\phi_1(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})\lor \phi_2(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})$$
so that we can represent an expression in $n$ variables as a pair of expressions in $n-1$ variables. 
We can ensure that $\phi_2\to\phi_1$ and with this condition, the pair $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ is uniquely determined.
Let's start enumerating:

- With $n=0$ we have $F$ and $T$
- With $n=1$ we have $F,v_1,T$ (from $F\to F$, $F\to T, T\to T$)
- With $n=2$ we have $F,v_1\land v_2,v_1,v_2,v_1\lor v_2,T$ (there ore six ways to pick $\phi_2\to\phi_1$ from $F\to v_1\to T$)
- With $n=3$ we have a total of $20$ way to pick $\phi_2\to \phi_1$ from the above (note that with the exception of $(v_1,v_2)$ a first expression in the above list always implies a second expression that is equal or to the right of the former).

I shall not write these 20 option down explicitly, nor follow this trail further.
Instead, we search OEIS for [2,3,6,20](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C6%2C20) and find as main hit the [number of monotone Boolean functions of $n$ variables](http://oeis.org/A000372), which seems to describe your problem exactly.